# Success at creating a bridge of two ethernet adapters but one won't connect

Tags: network-bridge

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I succeeded at creating a network bridge between the onboard ethernet and one on a PCI card. So far everything looks good but the pci ethernet won't connect to the outside device, which is a nas that works perfectly on the same card in win10.

I created the bridge from the following page using the nmcli method.

https://www.tecmint.com/create-network-bridge-in-ubuntu/

I then activated the bridge and checked the status of the bridge with the followings:

sudo nmcli conn up br0 (to activate)

sudo nmcli conn show --active (to confirm it's working)

All looks fine. But one thing remains a mystery, shouldn't the bridge have its own ip settings? I can't find where to do that. Right now the adapters have their own ip adresses.

Comment: A bridge is a layer 2 thing. IP addresses are layer 3 things. So a bridge can't have an IP

Comment: sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask  255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.72  metric  100 dev eth0